# Python recursive sequence related code

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to make a code that produces numbers according to the following formula...

T[n] = 1 + T[n-1] * 2

```
numList = []
numLisst.append (1)
#Begins with a term 1.

def numSequence ():
    while True:
        for i in range (1,12):
            #Temporally set numbers from 1 to 12
            numList[i] == 1+(numList[i-1]*2)
            break
    print (numList)

numSequence()
```

First of all, this brings an error, list index out of index

I'd like to see this code produce the fibonacci sequences, for example,,

1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127 , ....

I hope if I use this recursive program, I would be able to find out specific order of the numbers in an array, 
e.g. If I'd like to find out 3rd number in the array, should be whether 7 or 15 (It would depend how I would set it)

Comment: Your program is not recursive.

Comment: AFAIK, this is indeed a *recursive* sequence, but not a [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) one. Wikipedia says: *Fibonacci sequence [is] characterized by the fact that every number after the first two is the sum of the two preceding ones*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive implementation of your formula would be the following, assuming your base case was `T(1) = 1`

```
def T(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + T(n-1)*2
```

Some examples

```
>>> [T(i) for i in range(1,10)]
[1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511]
>>> T(15)
32767
```

Comment: I found out ho I get the specified term's number, but I don't get how I can get the listing such numbers. In your some examples part, T(i) for i in range (1,10), how can I make this display on my pyscripter?

Comment: You can say, for example, `for i in range(1, 10): print(T(i))`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this probem (not most Pythonic implementation, though...)

```
# T[n] = 1 + T[n-1] * 2

def nextFibonachi(n,i):
    n = 1 + n*2
    print(str(i)+": "+str(n))
    return n,i

fibArr = []
for i in range(0,100):
    if i == 0:
        n = 0
    n,i = nextFibonachi(n, i)
    fibArr.append(n)

print(fibArr)

m = 10
print("\n"+str(m)+": "+str(fibArr[m]))
```

Comment: You can set `n = 0` before the loop and drop the `if i == 0:`.

Comment: They explicitly said they work looking for a recursive solution, this is the iterative solution to the problem